# Reproducing FME Change Detector results in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sql

We would like to use the function change detector from FME in PostGIS.

[image: image from FME Transformers Guide]

We had a try with the following SQL-Statements but the function does not work. There are no results in the end. The single querys for added/deleted/unchanged are working but the problem with the function we got are the two loaded layers.

Does anybody now if there is a possibility to create an change detector function in PostGIS?

The result should create, depending on the data, one to three new layers (added/deleted/unchanged).

```
drop table if exists tab_cd_2;
create table tab_cd_2(
gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
nume varchar,
nume1 varchar,
nume2 varchar,
geom geometry(polygon, 32633));


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cd_3() RETURNS trigger AS

$$ begin

for NEW.nume in select count(landkreise_projected_added.name_3)
From public.landkreise_projected_added
 Where not exists (select geom from landkreise_projected_added
 where landkreise_projected_added.geom = landkreise_projected_deleted.geom)
loop

select count(landkreise_projected_added.name_3)
into tab_cd_2.nume1
FROM public.landkreise_projected_added
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT geom FROM landkreise_projected_deleted
 WHERE landkreise_projected_deleted.geom = landkreise_projected_added.geom);

begin
select count(landkreise_projected_added.name_3)
into tab_cd_2.nume2
FROM public.landkreise_projected_added
WHERE landkreise_projected_added.geom = landkreise_projected_deleted.geom;
end;

end loop;
RETURN tab_cd_2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';  

--  Trigger 
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fill_sp ON tab_cd_2;
CREATE TRIGGER fill_cd_3
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tab_cd_2
FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE cd_3();
```

Comment: ST_Difference and ST_Intersects http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html would be a starting points

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert into three tables, added, deleted, unchanged, then there is no need to return anything from the trigger, just do this work inside the trigger.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION cd_3() RETURNS trigger as $$
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO added (geom) 
       SELECT ST_Difference(new.geom, geom) 
       FROM public.landkreise_projected_added
       WHERE ST_Intersects(new.geom, geom); 
     INSERT INTO unchanged (geom) 
       SELECT ST_Intersection(new.geom, geom) 
       FROM public.landkreise_projected_added
       WHERE ST_Intersects(new.geom, geom);
     INSERT INTO deleted (geom) 
       SELECT ST_Difference(geom, new.geom) 
       FROM public.landkreise_projected_added
       WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, new.geom); 

      RETURN new;
    END
 $$  language plpgsql;

--  Trigger as before
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fill_sp ON tab_cd_2;
CREATE TRIGGER fill_cd_3
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tab_cd_2
FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE cd_3();
```

I would imagine that in practice, you might want to add a `timestamp column` to the added, unchanged and deleted tables and possibly a geometry id in the where clause otherwise you will be calculating changes against all polygons, which is probably not what you want.

Alternatively, you can also do a check that the new/old geometries intersect, if you are not using a geometry id, otherwise you will end up with lots of `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY` in your change/deleted/unchanged tables.

Note that the added and deleted operations both use ST_Difference, but with the order of the geom and new.geom reversed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The code is working but the access to the secound layer is missing (landkreise_projected_deleted). How can I access to the secound layer?

Comment: You should add a comment not an answer. I didn't see this until now :D. I called the table deleted, do you want it to be called andkreise_projected_deleted?